# Hash bytes32 and uint32 in Soldiity 0.5.8

Tags: solidity, hash, solidity-0.5.x

How can we efficiently calculate a hash value for a combination of bytes32 and integer value?

Like in JavaScript `"someString" + someInt`.

I tried:

```
function fx(bytes32 _left, uint32 _right) public returns (bytes32 hash) {
    hash = keccack256(_left + _right); // wrong
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keccak256` needs a `bytes` input (dynamic array of bytes). An easy way to convert everything to bytes and concatenate the bytes together is the ABI encoder.

```
function fx(bytes32 _left, uint32 _right) public pure returns (bytes32 hash) {
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_left,_right)); // right
}
```

I added `pure` because this function does not need access to storage and can return a value immediately, without mining, if called by a client. `pure` is generally the right way to go for such computations.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Pure clarification was very useful, thanks.